# Como pegar uma palavra que contém um caractere específico?

Tags: html, jquery, string, div

Tenho essa string em uma div:

```
"Sofá 3 Lugares Tiffany em Veludo 2,12m Aquila"
```

Quero pegar o texto das palavras que contenham **"`,`"** e retornar-las. Ex.: **2,12m**

Comment: Poste por favor o conteúdo total de onde você está extraindo essas informações.

Comment: Como assim ela mesma

Comment: "palavras" ou "palavra"? O resultado pode variar se vc quer como resultado apenas 1 palavras ou mais de uma, ou nenhuma. A div sempre terá a string com vírgula?

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi muito bem o que você quer, mas seria algo do tipo?

Split na palavra:

var palavra = "Sofá 3 Lugares Tiffany em Veludo 2,12m Aquila"

```
var palavraSplittada = palavra.split(" ");
```

Depois você faz um for para caminhar nesse vetor:

["Sofá", "3", "Lugares", "Tiffany", "em", "Veludo", "2,12m", "Aquila"]

```
for(let i = 0; i<=palavraSplittada.length; i++){
    if(palavraSplittada[i].contains(",") return palavraSplittada[i]
}
```

Caso uma das posições tenha a "," ele irá retornar essa palavra, você pode fazer algo nesse estilo.

Answer (score 0):

Uma das maneiras de fazer isso é utilizando o método [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro) junto com o método [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) para ver se a string contém a **`,`** e retornar esse parte da string:

```js
let string = 'Sofá 3 Lugares Tiffany em Veludo 2,12m Aquila';
let array = string.split(' ');

let filtro = array.filter(valor => valor.includes(','))

console.log(filtro);    // em forma de array
console.log(String(filtro));   // em forma de string
```